# Error al intentar convertir un archivo .xml a un objeto java con JAXB usando Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

El archivo que estoy intentando convertir es el siguiente:

"/src/xmlsrc/users.xml" :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<users>
    <user>
        <username>Admin</username>
        <password>admin</password>
    </user>
    <user>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>123</password>
    </user>
</users>
```

Las clases java que van a almacenar los datos del .xml son las siguientes:

1)"model/entity/Users.class" :

```
package model.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "users")
public class Users {

    ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Users() {

    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="users")
    @XmlElement(name="user")
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

}
```

2)"model/entity/User.class" :

```
package model.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlType(propOrder= {"username","password"})
public class User {
    
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public User() {
        
    }

    @XmlElement(name="username")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="password")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
}
```

El método con el intento acceder a los datos del xml se encuentra en la clase siguiente:

"model/dao/UserDao.class" :

```
package model.dao;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import model.entity.User;
import model.entity.Users;

public class UserDao {
    
    Controller controller;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<User> listUsers() {
        
        Users users = null;
        ArrayList<User> usersList = null;
        
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Users.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            users = (Users) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\LoginProject\\src\\xmlsrc\\users.xml"));
            
            
            if(users !=null) {
                usersList = users.getUsers();
                System.out.println(users.getUsers().get(0).getUsername());
            }
            
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return usersList;
    }
}
```

La clase con la que testeo si anda el método "listUsers()" es la siguiente:

"application/Main.class" :

```
package application;

import model.dao.UserDao;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        userDao.listUsers();
    }

}
```

Por último, cuando lo ejecuto me tira el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at model.dao.UserDao.listUsers(UserDao.java:35)
at application.executable.main(Main.java:9)
```

La línea 35 de UserDao.java corresponde a:

```
                System.out.println(users.getUsers().get(0).getUsername());
```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal, si me falta alguna anotación o algo? Agradecería mucho su ayuda.